# how to remove a directory name '-e'?

Tags: bash, filesystems

I have in a folder several empty directories named '-e' or '-v' and so on..  I don't know how those directories were made. This makes the command `ls -ltrd *` do not work. How can I remove those directories? I tried `\rm -r -e` and `\rm -r '\-e'` , or `\rm -r "-e"`,.. what else? They all didn't work and the shell interprets `-e` as an option.

Comment: `rm -r -- '-e'` should work

Comment: @PatrickBucher yes, that works! Thanks!